# How to show the result of JS/Html survey in a new page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a JS/HTML page for survey and i want to show the result in new page after clicking submit button.Right now the code written is showing the result in same page.If possible please let me know how can i do that.Right now the code written by me is showing the result on same page.

Js file :-

```
function displayRadioValue() {
let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
let section1Total = 0
let section2Total = 0
let section1Question = 0
let section2Question = 0
let section1Res = document.querySelector('.section-1-results')
let section2Res = document.querySelector('.section-2-results')
let result1 = ''
let result2 = ''

//Section 1
section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
if (radio.checked) {
  section2Question++
  section1Total += +radio.value
  }
 })

//Section 2
section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
if (radio.checked) {
  section1Question++
  section2Total += +radio.value
}
})

//Section 1
result1 += "<b>Results:</b><br>"
result1 += "Total: " + section1Total + "<br>"
result1 += "Percentage: " + ((section1Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
section1Res.innerHTML = result1

//Section 2
result2 += "<b>Results:</b><br>"
result2 += "Total: " + section2Total + "<br>"
result2 += "Percentage: " + ((section2Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
section2Res.innerHTML = result2

}
```

Html file :-

```
  <p>
 Select a radio button and click on Submit.
 </p>
 <div class="section-1">

<h2>Section 1</h2>
question 1:
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

<br> question 2:
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

<br> question 3:
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

  </div>
 <br>
 <div class="section-1-results"></div>

<div class="section-2">

<h2>Section 2</h2>
question 1:
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

<br> question 2:
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
<br> question 3:
<input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
<br> question 4:
<input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
 </div>
 <br>

<div class="section-2-results"></div>

<br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
 Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function store the `results` of each `section` in to this. So that we can send this `HTML` data to our `thankyou.html` next page. When you click on `submit` button.

You need another html page called `thankyou.html` which we will use to `redirect` the users when they hit the `submit` button.

For `redirecting` the to survey `thankyou` page page we can simply use `window.location.href` and pass the data to this `url` as `query` parameters.

In `thankyou.html` page you need to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) function to get all the data which we have sent from the `survey.html`. To get each section data we can use [.get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) function of `URLSearchParams` and get `section1` and `section2` separately displayed on our `thankyou.html` page.

Also, in `thankyou` page you need to define the `HTML` where this data will be displayed after.

I have tested this code and its working perfectly.

**survery.html**

```
<p>
  Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<div class="section-1">

  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

</div>

<div class="section-2">

  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
  <br> question 4:
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
</div>

<br>
<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
  Submit
</button>
```

**survey.html JS**

```
<script>

function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 1
  result1 += "<b>Results for section 1:</b><br>"
  result1 += "Total: " + section1Total + "<br>"
  result1 += "Percentage: " + ((section1Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
  let sect1 = encodeURIComponent(result1) //store data

  //Section 2
  result2 += "<b>Results for section 2:</b><br>"
  result2 += "Total: " + section2Total + "<br>"
  result2 += "Percentage: " + ((section2Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
  let sect2 = encodeURIComponent(result2) //store data

  //Redirect page
  window.location.href = "thankyou.html?section1="+sect1+"&section2="+sect2;
}

</script>
```

**thankyou.html page**

Add this `HTML` and `script` into you thanks you page.

```
<div id="results">
   <div class="section-1-results"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="section-2-results"></div>
</div>

<script>

//Results for each div
let section1Res = document.querySelector('.section-1-results')
let section2Res = document.querySelector('.section-2-results')

//Get data via URL
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let section1 = urlParams.get('section1'); //section1
let section2 = urlParams.get('section2'); //section2

//Apply results in new page
section1Res.innerHTML = section1
section2Res.innerHTML = section2

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...you are always a great help

Comment: @jugal You are welcome. Always happy to help. happy coding :)